# Why my program takes so long time?

Tags: python

I am dealing with a large txt file, there are overall 8050000 lines. A short example of the lines are:

```
usedfor zipper fasten_coat
usedfor zipper fasten_jacket
usedfor zipper fasten_pant
usedfor your_foot walk
atlocation camera cupboard
atlocation camera drawer
atlocation camera house
relatedto more plenty
```

I write a python code to read the lines, and store them as a dictionary. My code is:

```
dicCSK = {} 
for line in finCSK:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    try:
        r, c1, c2 = line.split(" ")
    except ValueError: print line
    if c1 not in dicCSK.keys():
        dicCSK[c1]= []
    str1 = r+" "+c2
    dicCSK[c1].append(str1)
```

However, I ran the program for over 20 hours, it is still running. So is there any better way to store them in a dictionary? My code is too slow. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a code review, so it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Aside: I would probably choose a different tool (and storage format) for this particular job -- details depending on exactly what one intends to *do* with the dictionary generated.

Comment: Aside [2]: `collections.defaultdict(list)` would avoid the need for the `c1 in dicCSK.keys()` check.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Is it though? I wouldn't consider anything "taking 20 hours" as working, unless it it really working on huge amounts of data (8M is a lot, but not 20 hours worth).

Comment: I don't agree this is asking for code review: the code has a specific problem -- it's too slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mistake: it generates a list of all keys in the dictionary and then scans over it.

```
if c1 not in dicCSK.keys():
    dicCSK[c1]= []
```

Instead:

```
if c1 not in dicCSK:
    dicCSK[c1] = []
```

Or instead, use a `defaultdict` to avoid the check.

```
dicCSK = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in finCSK:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    try:
        r, c1, c2 = line.split(" ")
    except ValueError:
        print line
    dicCSK[c1].append(r+" "+c2)
```

Also, probably you also want the `dicCSK[c1].append(r+" "+c2)` statement under an `else` clause of the `try/except` otherwise it will execute even when there's a `ValueError` exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is faster now. However, my program terminated with an error : `MemoryError`. Because I have four large files. It happens when the program starts to deal with the second file.

Comment: My computer has 8GB memory

Comment: @flyingmouse OK, but that sounds like a separate problem. If this answer answered the question you asked satisfactorily, perhaps accept it and start a new question with the new problem (assuming it's clear and specific enough).

Comment: thanks for your answer, the new question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347397/how-to-solve-the-memory-error-in-python