# How to solve the memory error in Python

Tags: python, memory

I am dealing with several large txt file, each of them has about 8000000 lines. A short example of the lines are:

```
usedfor zipper fasten_coat
usedfor zipper fasten_jacket
usedfor zipper fasten_pant
usedfor your_foot walk
atlocation camera cupboard
atlocation camera drawer
atlocation camera house
relatedto more plenty
```

The code to store them in a dictionary is:

```
dicCSK = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in finCSK:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    try:
        r, c1, c2 = line.split(" ")
    except ValueError:
        print line
    dicCSK[c1].append(r+" "+c2)
```

It runs good in the first txt file, but when it runs to the second txt file, I got an error `MemoryError`.

I am using window 7 64bit with python 2.7 32bit, intel i5 cpu, with 8Gb memory. How can I solve the problem?

Further explaining:
I have four large files, each file contains different information for many entities. For example, I want to find all information for `cat`, its father node `animal` and its child node `persian cat` and so on. So my program first read all txt files in the dictionary, then I scan all dictionaries to find information for `cat` and its father and its children.

Comment: Is this your real code? i think not. For example what is finCSK?

Comment: Why do you need this data in a dictionary? Put it into a database or some similar storage that allows you to query it.

Comment: @e4c5, I neglect the input process in my question, I read files, and `fin` opens the file

Comment: @DisplayName, I need to do more things after I read them in dictionary. So I need them in my code.

Comment: What do you have to do? Are you sure that storing the data in memory is the best approach for you actual problem?

Comment: How do you know that it's not the input part that's causing problems then? Anyway what exactly are you trying to do. Show a bit of the desired output as well. This looks like something that can be trivially done with something like sed. Or wait, you are on windows.

Comment: @DisplayName, yes I have to. I need to read four large txt file, store them in the dictionary, and scan all dictionaries to find the same entity, its father node and children node, and gather all information. And I need to do the same thing for many entities.

Comment: I still don't see anything in your description that requires this to be done in memory.

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: I agree with @DisplayName yet however if you still want to overcome this problem by bruteforece, use an AWS instance. shouldn't cost you $1-2

Comment: What is a "node", a "farther", and a "child"? The snippet you provides does not tell us anything about the structure of the data.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simplest solution: You're probably running out of virtual address space (any other form of error usually means running really slowly for a long time before you finally get a `MemoryError`). This is because a 32 bit application on Windows (and most OSes) is limited to 2 GB of user mode address space (Windows can be tweaked to make it 3 GB, but that's still a low cap). You've got 8 GB of RAM, but your program can't use (at least) 3/4 of it. Python has a fair amount of per-object overhead (object header, allocation alignment, etc.), odds are the strings alone are using close to a GB of RAM, and that's before you deal with the overhead of the dictionary, the rest of your program, the rest of Python, etc. If memory space fragments enough, and the dictionary needs to grow, it may not have enough contiguous space to reallocate, and you'll get a `MemoryError`.

Install a 64 bit version of Python (if you can, I'd recommend upgrading to Python 3 for other reasons); it will use more memory, but then, it will have *access* to a *lot* more memory space (and more physical RAM as well).

If that's not enough, consider converting to a `sqlite3` database (or some other DB), so it naturally spills to disk when the data gets too large for main memory, while still having fairly efficient lookup.

Comment: I install a 64bit python just now. It runs further than my original program, however I still got the `memory error` after half of my memory (about 4Gb was used). I feel strange that why the error happens when there is still the half memory available.

Comment: @flyingmouse: Are you running without a page file? Normally, even if you did use the physical RAM, it should keep running (if more slowly) until the page file is full. If there is no page file, then a sufficiently huge dictionary getting resized could hit the issue around 4 GB; if you've got enough data to be hitting that, then I strongly recommend switching to a DB (a simple one like `sqlite3` which ships as a Python module, or a more powerful one like PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.).

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your example text is representative of all the text, one line would consume about 75 bytes on my machine:

```
In [3]: sys.getsizeof('usedfor zipper fasten_coat')
Out[3]: 75
```

Doing some rough math:

```
75 bytes * 8,000,000 lines / 1024 / 1024 = ~572 MB
```

So roughly 572 meg to store the strings alone for one of these files. Once you start adding in additional, similarly structured and sized files, you'll quickly approach your virtual address space limits, as mentioned in @ShadowRanger's answer.

If upgrading your python isn't feasible for you, or if it only kicks the can down the road (you have finite physical memory after all), you really have two options: write your results to temporary files in-between loading in and reading the input files, or write your results to a database. Since you need to further post-process the strings after aggregating them, writing to a database would be the superior approach.