# How to split a very long line into several lines on Python?

Tags: python, xml

I needed to add "\n" to each tag in my xml so I can look through the file normally(about 300,000 lines in the file merged into 1 (opened with EmEditor and 16 lines were displayed))

However, when I try to read file and replace the tags, it gives out Memory Error

```
for line in open('file.xml', encoding='UTF-8'):
    main_line = line.replace('<root>', '\n<root>')
    with open('the_file.xml', 'a', encoding='UTF-8') as x:
        x.write(main_line)
```

There is no copy of the data, and pressing 300,000 times replace makes no sense.

Can I edit a file and bypass Memory error on Python?

Comment: Isn't line-by-line just one line?  I thought they were merged into one line.

Comment: Um... yeah, that's one line, I apologize for the interpretation)

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching and found this answer to a similar question: [How to solve the memory error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347397/how-to-solve-the-memory-error-in-python/37347584). TLDR: You are probably running out of RAM. Install 64 bit python or use a database like sqlite3 as the user ShadowRanger suggested. I hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: I've got a 64-bit python last and 16 gigabytes of ram
in the PC, the file itself is 2 gigabytes in size, and even if the whole file is put into memory, there should be a lot of free space... About SQLite I am a fan, and I think it is better to look for another method...

Answer (score 0):

You're re-opening your output file once per loop iteration. That's unnecessary and it may be contributing to your out-of-memory issue.  Consider opening the file only once instead:

```
with open('input_file.xml', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as input_file, open(
        'output_file.xml', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        output_file.write(line.replace('<root>', '\n<root>'))
```

Or just use `sed`:

```
sed 's/<root>/\n<root>/g' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the error has not been solved =(

Comment: I'll try sed now, might help.

Comment: cmder gives `Cannot find the file.` when i try `sed 's/<root>/\n<root>/g' "file.xml" > "the_file1.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "file.xml.xml"
b = "the_file.xml"
with open(a, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input, open(b, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    for line in input:
        main = line.replace('<root>', '\n<root>')
        out.write(main)
```

Comment: An explanation of the code would be useful. Also it's recommended to use descriptive variable names instead of "a" and "b"