# KeyError: 'torch', memory error ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.: AWS elastic beanstalk, django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, torch

So I have installed torch in my local machine and it is working correctly, but while deploying it in aws it show the following error.

I am trying to deploy my django app on AWS elastic beanstalk but I am facing the following error.

```
    2021-04-20 18:00:43    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2021-04-20 18:00:46    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2021-04-20 18:00:57    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.
2021-04-20 18:00:57    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.  
2021-04-20 18:01:01    ERROR   [Instance: i-0eee746bc342a71cd] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2021-04-20 18:01:01    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-04-20 18:01:01    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0eee746bc342a71cd'. Aborting the operation.
2021-04-20 18:01:01    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

My eb-engine.log

```
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.6.1%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl (5.7 MB)
Collecting torch==1.8.1+cpu

2021/04/20 18:00:57.931655 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 2. Stderr:ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name]
KeyError: 'torch'
.
.
.
.
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 671, in _unpack
    ret[key] = self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 684, in _unpack
    return bytes(obj)
MemoryError
```

My requirements.txt

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision==0.6.1+cpu
torch==1.8.1+cpu
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install torch in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800318/how-to-install-torch-in-python)

Comment: @NKSM Hey, Thanks for responding. I have installed torch in my local machine and it is working perfectly, but when I try to deploy it in aws it shows this error.