# Cleaning Json files in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary, tweets

I want to combine multiple json files in a dictionary and copy selected fields.

I am giving the code below. The json files are a collection of twitter data. The json files are corrupted so the individual lines are read.

Please help me with the error

```
import json
import os

path = "E:/proj/Project tweets/2019_07_01/01/"
filelist = os.listdir(path)



for filename in filelist:
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                json_lines = json.loads(line)
                try:
                    tags = ["created_at", "text", "user_location"]
                    data = json.dumps(json_lines)

                    for i in data:
                        if i not in tags:
                            del data[i]
                    with open('out_01_01.json', 'a') as file:
                        file.write(data)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

Comment: `data = json.dumps(json_lines)` : `data` is now a `string`

Comment: You're mistake lays within `for i in data` loop (incorrect iterable)

Answer (score 0):

the line causing this: `data = json.dumps(json_lines)`

`json.dumps()` returns a JSON formatted string

see [https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html](http://data%20=%20json.dumps(json_lines))

Answer (score 0):

With making the least changes to your code:

```
import json
import os

path = "E:/proj/Project tweets/2019_07_01/01/"
filelist = os.listdir(path)

for filename in filelist:
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                json_line = json.loads(line)
                try:
                    tags = ["created_at", "text", "user_location"]
                    for i in json_line:
                        if i not in tags:
                            del json_line[i]
                    with open('out_01_01.json', 'w') as file:
                        file.write(json.dumps(json_line))
                except ValueError:
                    continue
```

However, your code can be improved in several ways.

If lines can be corrupted:

```
import json
import os

path = 'E:/proj/Project tweets/2019_07_01/01'
filelist = [filex if filex.endswith('.json') for filex in os.listdir(path)]  
tags = {'created_at', 'text', 'user_location'}
output = []

for filename in filelist:
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        try:
            json_line = json.loads(line)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            continue
        output.append(dict((k, v) if k in tags for k, v in json_line.values()))
with open('out_01_01.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dump(output, f)
```

Otherwise you could just do:

```
import json
import os

path = 'E:/proj/Project tweets/2019_07_01/01'
filelist = [filex if filex.endswith('.json') for filex in os.listdir(path)]  
tags = {'created_at', 'text', 'user_location'}
output = []

for filename in filelist:
    output = [dict((k, v) if k in tags for k, v in json_line.values()) for json_line in (json.loads(l) for l in open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r').readlines())]

with open('out_01_01.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(output, f)
```

---

The problem was that `data` is a JSON string in your example, but you were apparently assuming that `data` would be a dict. In fact, `json_lines` is a dict and should better be named `json_line`.

NB: You should never name a variable `file` because file is a reserved name in Python. Besides, I don't see where a ValueError could occur in the try-block, but a JSONDecodeError could appear when you call `json.loads`.

Comment: i tried the suggested program but 'Memory Error' is present.

Comment: `MemoryError` means you [ran out of virtual address space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347584). Which version did you try? I modified the last so that the lines aren't read into a list at once, but are yielded by a generator expression. However, in the version with the least changes, one line after another is read and written, so there shouldn't be much memory required.