# Huggingface transformers unusual memory use

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have the following code attempting to use XL transformers to vectorize text:

```
  text = "Some string about 5000 characters long"

  tokenizer = TransfoXLTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('transfo-xl-wt103', cache_dir=my_local_dir, local_files_only=True)
  model = TransfoXLModel.from_pretrained("transfo-xl-wt103", cache_dir=my_local_dir, local_files_only=True)

  encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt') 
  output = model(**encoded_input)
```

This produces:

```
    output = model(**encoded_input)
  File "/home/user/w/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/w/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_transfo_xl.py", line 863, in forward
    output_attentions=output_attentions,
  File "/home/user/w/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/w/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_transfo_xl.py", line 385, in forward
    dec_inp, r, attn_mask=dec_attn_mask, mems=mems, head_mask=head_mask, output_attentions=output_attentions,
  File "/home/user/w/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/w//default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_transfo_xl.py", line 338, in forward
    attn_score = attn_score.float().masked_fill(attn_mask[:, :, :, None], -1e30).type_as(attn_score)
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at CPUAllocator.cpp:64] . DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory: you tried to allocate 2007869696 bytes. Error code 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
```

I'm a little perplexed by this because this is asking for 2007869696, which is only 2GB and this machine has 64G of RAM. So I both don't understand why it is asking for this, and even more, why it is failing to get it.

Where can I change the setting that controls this and allow this process more RAM?  This is such a small invocation of the example code, and I just see very few places that would even accept this argument.

Comment: Pytorch allocates with 64byte alignment, perhaps that can give a clue -  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8cdb638c6242e9278a971733ccbac9fe0cdd2117/c10/core/CPUAllocator.cpp#L57

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347397/how-to-solve-the-memory-error-in-python

Comment: Thanks, @Aroo.  I'm certainly on a 64 bit system.  Is there something else I missed in that link?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are using the gpu instead of cpu?

Try to run the python script with `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python script.py`. This will produce the correct python stack trace (as CUDA calls are asynchronous)

Also you can set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` using `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=device_number`.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21061) still open on the pytorch github, try to check it out.

Comment: Even with CPU, this is surprising, right?  2Gb allocation from 64Gb RAM is not much.

Comment: Yes sure, in fact it could be a pytorch bug. Just to say, have you tried to reduce the length of the string ```text```?